# for-each array manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, iteration

I'm trying to manipulate a char array by offsetting each char by some value.

By using the debugging function of my IDE I found out that everything works fine inside the loop. Out of the loop it seems like the array remained unchanged, this is (at least I believe) because the changes are only valid inside the for-each loop's scope.

How would I make these changes permanent, in a clean, professional way?

My code:

```
public class OffsetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String someString = "Cuckoo";
        String output = stringOffset(someString);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static String stringOffset(String s) {
        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
        for(char c : ca) {
            c += 3;
        }
        return String.valueOf(ca);
    }
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: `c` is just a copy of `c[i]`not a reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're copying the value to a separate variable and incrementing that, thus leaving the array unchanged.

Iterate over the array using an index variable instead. This allows you to set the value again:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < ca.length ; i++) {
    ca[i] += 3;
}
```

Comment: So there is no way doing this with a for each loop?

Comment: No. You’re lacking a way to set the values of the array you’re iterating over in that case.

Comment: @dchlebicki well, actually, there is the answer by Lalit, which uses a for-each with an external index variable, but it’s essentially  the same as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are working on a copy of String characters inside loop in your function, if you really need this you can do something like this:

```
public class classname{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String someString = "Cuckoo";
        String output = stringOffset(someString);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static String stringOffset(String s) {
        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
       char cb[] = new char[s.length()];//array to store new characters after offsetting
       int i=0;
        for(char c : ca) {
            c += 3;
            cb[i]=c;
            i++;
        }
        return String.valueOf(cb);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to create a second array.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou its just one of the way to do this.

Comment: This is really awkward. Just using a basic for loop would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without using a for loop:

```
public static String stringOffset(String s) {
    return s.codePoints()
            .map(c -> c + 3)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();

}
```

Alternatively, a slightly more efficient way which avoids reallocations:

```
public static String stringOffset(String s) {
    return s.chars()
            .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(s.length()),
                    (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) (c + 3)),
                    StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `s.toCharArray()` the String is transformed into a char[] array. The type `char` is a **primitive** type in Java, so the variable `c` in the loop has a copy of the value. If you changes the `c` variable, you're NOT modifying the original array.

If you need to modify a String, you need to build another String with the result, you can't modify the original String.

Comment: Even if the elements were of reference type, `r = doSomethingWith(r);` wouldn't replace the value in the array.